# I can't login with a password containing a plus sign in a .NET Core app when the password was reset with the UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync method

Tags: asp.net-core, passwords, special-characters

We have a web application in .NET Core in which you can reset your password (such functionality much wow) using the ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password) method of the UserManager class. We have the default settings about password validation (should be more than 6 symbols long, containing a digit, upper and lower character, a special symbol, etc). Everything works fine until you try to reset your password to one containing a + symbol. In that case the method returns a success but then you can't login with that password.

For example, if we have the password "Someth1ng_" it works, but if we have "Someth1ng+" it doesn't work. There are problems with other special symbols but we haven't taken the time to find out exactly which ones (the following are ok: *=_).

We've already checked whether the problem is with parameter passing from the client to the server and it's not - on the server the password is received as it was sent.

Could the problem be in the ResetPasswordAsync method? Has anybody had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue, in my case I found that some passwords may affect login as ssnaky described before, in my case the password failed when I entered durga%118  at first I thought that the char % was the responsable but then I entered the new password durga%%%% and it worked fine, so I asume that maybe is something within the ResetPasswordAsync method.

NOTE: I found my problem, it was an encoding issue at the login section.